# Trick to Remember Book 1 of Euclid?

Tags: geometry

Is there a trick or pattern to help remember the (48!) propositions in book 1 of Euclid's Elements?

Book 2 has a fairly nice picture summing it all up

http://www.gogeometry.com/geometry/euclid_elements_23_definiti.gif

and you can use basic algebra also

http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookII/bookII.html

and the definitions fit into a nice pattern too

http://www.gogeometry.com/geometry/euclid_elements_23_definiti.gif

but even remembering the 48 propositions in book 1 is a lot, maybe they clump together in patterns?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?  Knowing and understanding geometry seems much more worth, and anyway: after some time dwellin g with it, say teaching it, much of the material will stick...